# Compatibilidad de Apache Tomcat con C#

Tags: c#, genexus, tomcat

Estoy desarrollando un sistema con GeneXus en C#, pero IIS no me ayuda mucho porque me parece que no tiene una consola de comandos donde pueda verificar los errores que suelo cometer. Por lo que sé, Tomcat trabaja con Java, puesto que fue desarrollado en ese lenguaje, pero ¿alguien sabe si funciona para ejecutar aplicaciones web con C#?

Answer (score 0):

El tomcat sólo vale para aplicaciones web java, y no todas ellas según qué tecnologías empleen. No te valdría para c#.

Si entras a la web de tomcat podrás ver, en el primer párrafo de la descripción del proyecto, las tecnologías Java soportadas así como la ausencia de menciones a otros lenguajes.

Comment: En [este Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/07/23/publish-htmljs-website-to-linuxapache-using-visual-studio/) de MSDN dice que si se puede, más bien, me parece que la pregunta no está muy clara

Comment: Ese lino habla de Apache, no Apache Tomcat, que no es lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Según ha investigado efectivamente existe la posibilidad de hostear aplicaciones ASP.NET en Apache Servers (al menos a partir de determinadas versiones en adelante).

A tal fin habría que configurar el Apache con mod_mono que es un modulo que precisamente permite que Apache pueda servir aplicaciones ASP.NET en dos modalidades a saber:

a) WebForms
b) WebServices (del tipo SOAP basados en RPC)

Sin embargo, en lo personal, antes de embarcarme en un tema así, primero evaluaría muy bien si verdaderamente justifica el esfuerzo como así también investigaría un poco acerca de que tantas implementaciones de este tipo se conocen.-

Dejo aquí link de github como fuente de información

https://github.com/mono/website/blob/gh-pages/docs/web/aspnet.md